# how to change the gmail id associated with my developer account in android?

Tags: android

i have made a developer account on the android market after paying $25. Now i want to change the gmail username and password associated with my developer account to another gmail account of mine.
how do i do this?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [support page](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139626):

> Create a new Android Market publisher
>   account and pay the $25USD
>   registration fee. We are able to
>   cancel your original account and
>   refund the registration fee.

Comment: over here they are saying i have to pay $25 again and make a new account. then i can transfer my application from one account to another. i want to keep only one account and change the username.

Comment: Yes, you get a refund for the old account after you create the new account. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok. have you tried it? do they really refund your money... or its just something they say?